# Is it possible to refresh an Angular 2 Dialog and not it's parent?

Tags: angular, dialog

I want a user to be able to click a submit button inside a dialog in Angular 2 and it refresh/reload the dialog only.

Currently when using window.location.reload() it reloads the entire page.

Is this possible for just the dialog itself while using a button inside the dialog?

Comment: The better question is *why are you calling `window.location.reload`*. No, that will never reload just the dialog but you almost *never* should be calling that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using a template or a component to instantiate your dialog.
However, a dialog is a piece of UI with databindings like any other Angular component. Any data bound to your Dialog will be displayed when updated.

Just separate the model displayed by your dialog from the model displayed by your page, update it when needed and you should be good.

You should avoid using `window.location.reload()` as it makes you lose the JavaScript context. Even if your application state is represented by the URL (which is a good practice), you should not use it and there is barely no situation where you'd be forced to.

Comment: Is there a better way to refresh a page?

Comment: you don't "refresh" a page in Angular. Angular applications, like any other JavaScript applications are called "Single page applications". No offense, but you seem to be lacking basic understanding of what it is. If you're used to server side rendering, I suggest you read some doc, because it's pretty different.

Comment: I am 100% lacking a basic understanding so no worries there. Actually just rethinking about this I realized how to fix my issue without a refresh so thanks!